# Resize canvas of QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

Is there a way to resize the canvas of a `QPixmap`, similar to how an [image editor does it](http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/resources-images/photoshop-resize-image-and-canvas-tutorials/cropping-canvas-image-size.jpg) - by padding and clipping the image as necessary, but not scaling it?

If not, I assume I should create a new (compatible) `QPixmap`, and use [QPainter::drawPixmap()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpainter.html#drawPixmap) to place the original image appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such option. You need to create another pixmap and use `drawPixmap` as you said.